# RegEx for adding emphasis tag conditionally

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,
I am using the latest version of NotePad++. I would be very grateful if anyone out there can help me develop a Regex that adds an opening & closing emphasis tag within opening and closing `<para>` tags only when the `<para>` tag is preceded by an opening `<levelledPara>` tag.  Below is example code to clarify what I need the Regex to do:

FIND THIS TEXT STRING:
`<levelledPara><para>Text I need emphasized and unchanged</para>`

REPLACE WITH THIS TEXT STRING:
`<levelledPara><para><emphasis>Text I need emphasized and unchanged</emphasis></para>`

To summarize,  I need the Regex to add the opening and closing `<emphasis>` tags inserted within the `<para>` and `</para>` tags only when the opening `<para>` tag is preceded by an opening `<levelledPara>` tag. Is it possible for a Regex to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 1):

Search:

```
(<levelledPara><para>)(.*?)(<\/para>)
```

Replace:

```
\1<emphasis>\2<\/emphasis>\3
```